# Bootstrap dropdown menu content covered by content below:

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqr0444isul1rky/Screenshot%202014-09-23%2022.06.49.png?dl=0

Above is an image of the about us dropdown in the header.  When I click it, the below content is currently taking priority over the dropdown menu content.

This should not be the case but it is.  Below is a picture of what it looks like when I click it:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ud446l7hpz7veg/Screenshot%202014-09-23%2022.08.15.png?dl=0

As you can see it's white and the content below is covering it from showing.  There is a little white space but it's not taking up what it should.

I've searched around SO/Google and most answers say to add a higher z-index.  I have tried this and it did NOT work.

This is the current CSS for the header (non-bootstrap but it works) and it shows the content properly:

```
#nav > li > ul {
position: absolute;
border: 5px solid #008553;
border-width: 5px 0px 6px;
padding: 27px 26px 30px 26px;
left: -9999em;
top: 35px;
width: 908px;
background: #f1f7f4;
z-index: 500;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.3);
}
```

What can be the solution to this?  There is other CSS from a wordpress website -- how can I tell the dropdown menu to be given priority to take up this space?

Comment: you need to add some code try to make a http://jsfiddle.net/ file for better understanding

Comment: Far too difficult to replicate with all of the different CSS/HTML unfortunately.

Comment: additionally to @RoySonasish's comment, you can also use http://www.bootply.com/new to test bootstrap stuff

Comment: The problem is there is extra CSS that's causing this problem and I need to know how to override that CSS so this works properly.

Comment: @asgwar12 no need to write the same thing in different words twice, we all know this post needs more code to work with...

Comment: What CSS should I post please?

Comment: Edited OP with the current nav's css that isn't bootstrap but works.

Comment: Just for the curiosity, why do you need a dropdown for About us?

Comment: We have links in the dropdown foreach employee and links to about, contact, etc.  I'm just the developer man I don't make the business decisions.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a,.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
      position: absolute;
      border: 5px solid #008553;
      border-width: 5px 0px 6px;
      padding: 27px 26px 30px 26px;
      left: -9999em;
      top: 35px;
      width: 908px;
      background: #f1f7f4;
      z-index: 500;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.3);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.3);
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Nothing's coming up still.